# Height and Width of an appended d3 circle is too large

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have an onClick function on each of my dots, and noticed that the height and width of each dot/circle is too large. So if two dots were close to each other in a scatter plot, it will be difficult to select one over the other since the clickable area is too large. When I inspect the circle on chrome, the width and height of the circle/dot is 3.5px (the r value) but the overall width and height of the element/clickable area is 12.4px.

I tried putting an attribute of height and width to a set value, but this does not change the height and width of the clickable area. I also tried adding a view-box attribute to the circle but that did not change the height and width of the clickable area.

```
svg
      .selectAll('.dot')
      .data(this.state.data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'dot')
      .attr('r', 3.5)
      .attr('cx', d => {
        return x(d.complexity)
      })
      .attr('cy', d => {
        return y(d.value)
      })
      .style('fill', () => {
        return color(Math.random() * 50)
      })
      // .style('width', '3.5px')
      .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
      .attr('stroke-width', '100')
```

I expected that the clickable area would be just the circle/dot, but it's not.

Comment: you may be able to use the pointer-events svg property https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/svg-interaction-pointer-events-property/

Comment: Might it be because you set the `stroke-width` of the circle at 100px? Even if it's transparent it's still there.

Comment: @CathyHa That solved it!! thanks so much!!!!

Comment: No worries, happy to help.